# How to use calc() with function inside?

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way to do the following in a single line?

```
--widthA: get-vw(20px);
font-size: calc(5px + var(--widthA));
```

Since I need to set a minimum `font-size`. The `get-vw` function will calculate 20px in vw and I need to add 5px on top of that.

Comment: You might want to tag this SASS/LESS.

Comment: added as well, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can write this in one line (without variable) using [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) (`#{...}`):

```
font-size: calc(5px + #{get-vw(20px)});
```

**demo (with example function):** https://jsfiddle.net/wccoLefp/

> Sass allows any text in these function calls, including nested parentheses. Nothing is interpreted as a SassScript expression, with the exception that interpolation can be used to inject dynamic values.
> [Sass: Special Functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/special-functions#calc-clamp-element-progid-and-expression)